# Failed To Build Android Application After Adding Firebase Libs

Tags: android, firebase, build

Hi I Need help i have created a new android app now i want to implement firebase Notifications on it.
But After Adding The Libs. I am not able to build i am getting the following Error
But My Application Is Working Fine Only i Am not able to Build it.

**please help me to Resolve this problem**

```
Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 127989 \u003e 65536 ; # fields: 66243 \u003e 65536)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:mergeDexDebug
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate.run(DexMergingTask.kt:316)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTask.taskAction(DexMergingTask.kt:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
```

java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
    Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
    The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
    Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)

```
    > Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
      The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
      Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 2m 41s
    20 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 11 up-to-date
```

Comment: can you share your app module gradle?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Enable multidex build.

Make below changes in app gradle. Add ***multiDexEnabled true***

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       ....
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

In dependencies add:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Comment: is this only solution over firebase issue?

Comment: this solution helped me on react native fb-sdk problem

Comment: this solution also helped me on react native onesignal sdk problem.

Comment: yeah, you can chech the source in the rnfirebase docs: https://rnfirebase.io/enabling-multidex